# Google Analytics reporting data before tag is even up

Tags: google-analytics

So I've been working on a website for a while. GA account has been up for a couple months but I waited for the website to be finished before putting up the actual JS tag.

In the meantime, the website is being HTTP password restricted (basic authentication) so it isn't even accessible unless you know the user/pwd combination.

To my surprise, I realized today that GA has logged several hundred views to the root of my website. Paths are mostly things like:

- /
- /?from=http://social-widget.xyz/
- /?from=http://www.traffic2cash.xyz/

Bounce% and exit% both at 100% for all of them.

I realize this looks like referral spam, and there are ways to prevent it. Came across this upon googling:
http://botcrawl.com/block-social-widget-xyz-referral-spam-in-google-analytics/

My question is: how can GA log anything anyway when no tag is up and the website isn't even accessible?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's spam. They hit Google Analytics directly with random GA codes and don't even go through your website.

GA can't tell if these are real hits (from website visits) or fake hits (from spam bots who hit GA directly calling the same ode as they would if on the website). Though arguably they should do more about this.

Massively annoying - particularly when first starting out as this can be a heavy proportion of your "traffic".

It's easy to set up a filter rule is to catch a lot of this by filtering on hostname. As they are randomly hitting GA and don't even know what website they are hitting GA for, they don't usually set this correctly. Real traffic should only come from yourwebsitedomain.com so add a filter for that.

Comment: Thanks. Following your advice, I found [this article](https://megalytic.com/blog/how-to-filter-out-fake-referrals-and-other-google-analytics-spam) advising to create a segment to try out the rule before committing to the filter. Looks like it'll do!

Comment: Good to keep a completely unfiltered view anyway. I have two views "All traffic" and "Real Traffic" and mostly use the latter. I also filter out my own IP from that and switch to "All traffic" if testing something where I want to see my own hits.

Answer (score 0):

STRONG piece of advice: abandon the default UA-########-1 tracking code of your new website -- simply do not use it!

Create a second and third property on the Admin screen, then use the tracking code for the third property. You will immediately see a lot less spam. No filters or segments necessary!

If you want the whole sad story about spam visits in GA, I have been maintaining the Definitive Guide article for over a year now:
http://help.analyticsedge.com/spam-filter/definitive-guide-to-removing-google-analytics-spam/