# Googly Analytics show strange page title

Tags: google-analytics, page-title

I can understand, why is shown page title on home page http://maps.ilovevitaly.com/ ? I havenot this title. See the sceen and help, please:

[image: Google Analitycs]

Answer (score 0):

It's spam hoping you'll visit that site.

See here: [Google Analytics reporting data before tag is even up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34979037/google-analytics-reporting-data-before-tag-is-even-up/34979119#34979119)

And here: https://www.ohow.co/stop-how-to-travel-and-make-money-online-for-free-with-maps-ilovevitaly-com-referral-organic-spam-google-analytics/